# Enlarging border is changing the size of child element

Tags: css

I am trying to create an animation on hover of profile pics.

Basically a parent div has rounded corners so that the image look like a circle. When hovering it a border is increased from 0px to 7px.The problem is that the image located inside the child div is shrinking because I have set it's width to 100%.

I can't set a fixed width for the image because the image has to fill the div wether it is big or small.

Is there a way to fix this ?

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.element:hover {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  border: 7px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.element img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <a href="action"><img src="//myapp.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image" alt="alt" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide a workable example next time https://jsbin.com/soqubawuqa/edit?html,css,output  are you sure it is getting smaller? It looks like there is just a border being created

Comment: you can make the border 7px initialy with a transparent color

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box` too?

Comment: To Paulie: `box-sizing:border-box;` on parent div has no effect. To Temani: Actually my border is already slightly transparent. But i can't even see any transparency because the image below is shrunk. As my background is white, the border is 100% white

Comment: Pre-hover... **you have no border** as it has no width.

Comment: Thanks Akin, yes the border is created but if you look closely the image below is slightly shrinking. By setting border to 50px it gets more visible.

Comment: Hi Paulie, yes pre hover I just want the plain image. Only on hover I want to see the border grow to final size. Though the image in div is shrinking too. This is my problem. trying to find a solution for making the image 100% width stay untouched.

Comment: So set a 7px **completely transparent** border prehover and then just change the color...as as been suggested. Problem solved! `border: 7px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);`

Comment: Oh ok. Yes it does work. The effect is a bit different: the image is smaller from start and the border thickness is not growing. But I quite like the effect and I think I will use it. Thanks

Comment: To avoid the image size being smaller from the beginning, put another border on top of the image(put a div inside of element with width and height 100%, place border on it). The original border remains to make the image a circle, but don't animate that border. Animate the border inside of element, since it is on top(absolute) it will not shrink the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you could to accomplish what you want. I removed some irrelevant styles to make it simpler.

Instead of using `element`'s border, you just need to create another border inside of the `element` and use it to animate the hover, this way your image will not be small to begin with and won't change size when you hover

https://jsfiddle.net/py04y4x1/2/

```
.element {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
}

.element:hover .border {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  border: 7px solid red;
}

.element img {
  width: 100%;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="element">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <a href="action"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/VT-PqxMMsA2wPy7kzmuKGDIzaA3AGuXKExqnfOfwTEy5AvLIMTranbfNGheRr457RD4=w300" alt="alt" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Huaganism it is what I need. I need to tweak a bit because the border of `.border` is not perfectly covering images on the edges of the border but it should be easy to do.